# Correct way of unpacking operation type from network application

Tags: c++, oop, network-programming

I come from python world, and as a weekend project I decided to write a simple UDP server in c++. I have a question regarding correct way of discovering the type of incoming request. My approach is to have a class for every possible type of request. Upon packet arrival I have to unpack it's OPID (operation id) and instantiate correct class. To do that I have to bind OPIDs with the classes, and the only way I'm familiar of doing this in c++ involves huge switch:case block. Doing this doesn't really feels right for me, also If I understand UncleBob correctly, this goes against few OOP practices. As code describes the best one's intentions, here's python equivalent of what I'm trying to do with c++.

```
class BaseOperation:

    OPID = 0

    def process(packet_data):
        raise NotImplementedError("blah blah")

class FooOperation(BaseOperation):

    OPID = 1

    def process(packet_data):
        print("Foo on the packet!")

class BarOperation(BaseOperation):

    OPID = 2

    def process(packet_data):
        print("Bar on the packet!")

opid_mappings = {
    FooOperation.OPID: FooOperation,
    BarOperation.OPID: BarOperation
}
```

Somewhere in code handling the incoming packet

```
def handle_connection(packet):
    try:
        operation = opid_mappings[get_opid(packet)]()
    except KeyError:
        print("Unknown OPID")
        return
    operation.process(get_data(packet))
```

Comment: Give [`std::map<OPID_type, BaseOperation*>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) a look. To get your full effect, `BaseOperation` will need to overload `operator()`.

Comment: Ok, So You are suggesting to make a global map and fill it up in main, or some other place during initialization?

Comment: Oke, thanks. I decided to go with a singleton, in it's constructor I'm going to fill the map up.

Comment: Pretty much, but you don't have to load it in `main`.  You should be able to statically allocate if you are compiling to the C++11 standard or better. Will post a quick answer because it doesn't fit or format in a comment.

Comment: Took a little longer that I figured because I did try following the `std::unique_ptr` rabbit hole on the off chance it was easy to explain. Doesn't quite work as safely as I'd like without C++14 and `make_unique`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Really quick hack of object-based solution. This might not be the right way to go in our wonderful new C++11 world of `std::function`.

If the children of BaseOperation need to store state, go objects!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

class BaseOperation
{
protected:
    int  OPID;

public:
    virtual ~BaseOperation()
    {

    }
    virtual int operator()() = 0;

};

class FooOperation:public BaseOperation
{

public:
    static constexpr int OPID = 1;
    FooOperation()
    {

    }
    int operator()()
    {
        // do parsing
        return OPID; // just for convenience so we can tell who was called
    }
};

constexpr int FooOperation::OPID; // allocate storage for static

class BarOperation:public BaseOperation
{

public:
    static constexpr int OPID = 2;
    BarOperation()
    {

    }
    int operator()()
    {
        // do parsing
        return OPID; // just for convenience so we can tell who was called
    }
};

constexpr int BarOperation::OPID; // allocate storage for static

std::map<int, BaseOperation*> opid_mappings{
    {FooOperation::OPID, new FooOperation()},
    {BarOperation::OPID, new BarOperation()}
};

int main()
{

    std::cout << "calling OPID 1:" << (*opid_mappings[1])() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "calling OPID 2:" << (*opid_mappings[2])() << std::endl;

    for (std::pair<int, BaseOperation*> todel: opid_mappings)
    {
        delete todel.second;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This also ignores the fact that there is probably no need for the map. If the OPIDs are sequential, a good ol' dumb array solves the problem. I like the map because it won't screw up if someone moves a parser handler or inserts one into the middle of the list.

Regardless, this has a bunch of memory management problems, such as the need for the for loop deleting the parser objects at the bottom of `main`. This could be solved with [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), but this is probably a rabbit hole we don't need to go down.

Odds are really good that the parser doesn't have any state and we can just use a map of OPIDs and [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <functional>

static constexpr int FooOPID = 1;
int fooOperation()
{
    // do parsing
    return FooOPID;
}

static constexpr int BarOPID = 2;
int BarOperation()
{
    // do parsing
    return BarOPID;
}

std::map<int, std::function<int()>> opid_mappings {
    {FooOPID, fooOperation},
    {BarOPID, BarOperation}
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "calling OPID 1:" << opid_mappings[1]() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "calling OPID 2:" << opid_mappings[2]() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And because the parser's are kind of useless if you aren't passing anything in, one last tweak:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <functional>

struct Packet
{
    //whatever you need here. Probably a buffer reference and a length
};

static constexpr int FooOPID = 1;
int fooOperation(Packet & packet)
{
    // do parsing
    return FooOPID;
}

static constexpr int BarOPID = 2;
int BarOperation(Packet & packet)
{
    // do parsing
    return BarOPID;
}

std::map<int, std::function<int(Packet &)>> opid_mappings {
    {FooOPID, fooOperation},
    {BarOPID, BarOperation}
};

int main()
{

    Packet packet;
    std::cout << "calling OPID 1:" << opid_mappings[1](packet) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "calling OPID 2:" << opid_mappings[2](packet) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```